# SSRS export timespans more 24 hours to excel

Tags: sql, reporting-services, export-to-excel

friends. 
I have field in my report that contains time string 25:00:00. How can i export this field to excel and get column format [h]:mm:ss automatically?

Steps that i tried:

1. Used function System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90000). But it gave me result 1.01:00:00 and it exports to excel as General format.
2. Used expression for TextBox properties -> Number in SSRS like this:
   =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML","[h]:mm:ss","HH:mm"). It gave the same result as previous.

If there are some ideas how to decide this problem, I wait your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FORMAT function removes the actual data type of the column while exporting. So Instead i will suggest use FORMAT property (as in below screenshot)

[image]

Now if you try again & export report to excel it will export using the format property of that cell.

Comment: Thanks for responce but i tried your solution and again have columns in General format in excel